# Installing ROS on windows 7

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd-slam, asus, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

Can anyone help me with a ROS Electric installation on a windows machine. Ideally I'd love to do it on ubuntu but the PC doesn't belong to me so I can't change the platform.
I've read the tutorial on the website [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Windows) but it takes to many huge leaps in the build chain and I'm afraid my programming skills aren't up to it yet.
I'm using Visual studio 2010 and I have the final aim of doing a RGBD-SLAM with the ASUS Pro Live.

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36437/installing-ros-on-windows-7/) by [BrowCam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2597/browcam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BrowCam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2597/browcam/) on 2012-06-13**:
Thanks I'll try Fuete. Is there any chance someone could provide a short guide on how to get going, the instructions on ROS are really vague.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-06-19**:
If you make it work, please post a tutorial. I guess there would be many people interested in that.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2012-06-19**:
If you could elucidate what is confusing or difficult in the instructions for [fuerte](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Windows), please do so. I'll endeavour to update the information.

**Comment by [shocktube](https://answers.ros.org/users/9511/shocktube/) on 2013-12-04**:
Did you have any luck on this project? I was looking at doing the same thing with the Asus Xtion on Win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can use Fuerte, there is experimental Windows support already. Have a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Windows).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-08-07**:
If you are running Windows 10: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows